# Spring ResponseEntityExceptionHandler doesn't catch 404 error after an update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've updated my project from spring-boot:2.5.14 to spring-boot:2.7.11. (For reference the spring-webmvc was 5.3.20 before and is 5.3.27 now).This has caused one of my error handling responses to break. What's interesting is that all 4xx still work fine, except for 404.

For my error handling, I'm extending the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` that looks like this:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RestExceptionControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  //other fields and methods...
  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, @Nullable Object body, 
      HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    if (status.is4xxClientError()) {
      return getResponseParametersEntity(status, CustomStatus.REQUEST_NOT_ACCEPTED, 
          request.getLocale());
    }
    return super.handleExceptionInternal(ex, body, headers, status, request);
  }
```

I do have `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true` in my application.properties.

The problem within Spring that I was able to identify is that previously I was getting a NoHandlerException because that getHanlder function in DispatcherServlet was getting 4 handlers and returning a null since none of them matched:[4 handlers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMk0I.png)

Now, after the update, there are 6 of them and the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping gets returned instead of the null and the exception isn't thrown:[6 handlers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbL63.png)

How can I make my RestExceptionControllerAdvice handle the 404 like it did before?

I've tried searching for a solution but some seem outdated and some seem to point out that the `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true` is missing which in my case it's not. Also, what differs in my case is that this has worked in v 2.5.14 and now in 2.7.11 isn't.